# error when trying to read a file's date created property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Im trying to read the date created property of a File in my computer I am using the following lines of code:

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSDictionary *localFileProperties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:path error:&error];
NSLog(@"file date: %@",[localFileProperties fileModificationDate]);
```

But I get a (null) as an answer, and I don't know what I am doing wrong, I don't get an error, and when I inspect the NSDictionary description it has only this 5 keys:

```
Printing description of localFileProperties:
{
    NSFileSystemFreeNodes = 113416750;
    NSFileSystemFreeSize = 464555008000;
    NSFileSystemNodes = 121886742;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 16777218;
    NSFileSystemSize = 499248103424;
}
```

Am I missing something in my code? or what can be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the method name, or [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW9). `attributesOfFileSystemForPath:` is for a **file system**, not a single file.

You want [`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW8).